# Fit 2 images to the same width as a column with defined height

Tags: css, html, height, width

Having 2 images with different width and height. 
Is it possible to use CSS to create a column where both images (one above the other) fit 100% of column height, and make the images appear with the same width?
So far I'm using a server side equation to determine ideal width of a cotainer div, and using width 100% for the images, but I would prefer a solution 100% css to spare server processing.

here is my fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkNDY/1/)
css:

```
#container { height: 300px; background-color: black; overflow: hidden; }
#container .col { float: left; font-size: 0; }
#container .col img { width: 100%; }
```

html:

```
 <div id="container">
    <div class="col" style="width:174px">
    <img src="http://acasa.org.br/ensaio/grande/380.JPG">
    <img src="http://www.acasa.org.br/midia/thumb/MF-00002.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle seems to doe this successfuly. What's the issue?

Comment: The 174px is being calculated server side. I'm looking for a solution 100% client side.

Comment: You should re-work your question code to represent the default state of the problem not the server-fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

CSS

```
#container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
#container .col {
  width: 174px;
  background: red;
  float:left;
}
#container .col img {
  width: 174px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PkNDY/3/)

Comment: The 174px should be dynamic, because with different images the width will change.